# undefined method `update_attributes' for seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am getting undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass while running seed.rb file.

This is my seed file:-

```
Category.find_by_name('ATV').update_attribute(:rpp_prefix, 1)

Category.find_by_name('UTV/ATV (side-by-side)').update_attribute(:rpp_prefix, 2)
Category.find_by_name('Boat').update_attribute(:rpp_prefix, 3)
```

please let me know the solution for this seed file

Comment: Some of those records don't exist. Make sure they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try find_or_create_by_name, just to know what the exactly error is:

```
Category.find_or_create_by_name('ATV').update_attribute(:rpp_prefix, 1)

Category.find_or_create_by_name('UTV/ATV (side-by-side)').update_attribute(:rpp_prefix, 2)
Category.find_or_create_by_name('Boat').update_attribute(:rpp_prefix, 3)
```

Sure that you haven't wrote the name of the category wrong? You could also try

`Category.find_or_create_by_name('ATV').update_attributes(rpp_prefix: 1)` (update_attributes)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to update attribute for category that doesn't exist.

Try creating categories in your seed file before updating attributes, but I think it's better to create categories with proper attributes from the start.

Comment: but still i am getting same error.

Comment: Ttry using 'update attributes' instead 'update attribute'. 'Update attribute' is moved from last rails versions

Comment: not solved same error

Comment: try `Category.find_by_name('ATV').update_attribute(rpp_prefix: 1)`